# Flutter StompClient error Only static members can be accessed in initializers

Tags: flutter, dart, stomp

I am using the below to start the stomp client,

```
dynamic whenConnected(StompClient client, StompFrame frame) {
  print('SUCCESSFULLY CONNECTED SOCKET TO SERVER');
  print("Stomp client details ==  " + client.connected.toString() +  " " + client.config.toString() + "  " + client.runtimeType.toString());
  client.subscribe(
      destination: '/user/job/request',
      callback: (StompFrame frame) {
        List<dynamic> result = json.decode(frame.body);
        print(result);
      });
}

final stompClient = StompClient(
    config: StompConfig(
        url: 'ws://localhost:8442/ws',
        onConnect: whenConnected,
        onWebSocketError: (dynamic error) => print("STOMP SOCKET CONNECTION ERROR == " + error.toString()),
        stompConnectHeaders: {'token': 'asdfasdaskdjlds8798798asd9dslsakhsd'},
        webSocketConnectHeaders: {'token': 'asdfasdaskdjlds8798798asd9dslsakhsd'}
    )
);
```

but the flutter errors about the method whenConnected not being static

anyone have any idea?
this is from the flutter stompClient documentation

The issue with converting whenConnected to static is that, client will only be accessible within whenConnected

Comment: Try using a variable like whenConnectedResult and then initialize it in intiState with the call to whenConnected. Then use whenConnectedResult in stompClient().

Anytime I see an issue with an intializer, I always reach for initState. (Let me know if this is the answer, then I'll answer it below.)

Comment: But the flutter class is not a widget and doesn't have any init state. Also on top of that, every time I want to open socket connection, whenConnectedResult would be null as the Stompclient config has not been run yet